# Fast Method of Converting Character Array to ASCII Key Value

Tags: c++, arrays, ascii

I am making a program that reads a large amount of characters in a sequence from a file that consists of a-z and the number 0. An example would look like this:

```
a0dgiw00cffn0ai0cbiwa0...
```

I believe I converted this sequence to a character array with this:

```
strncpy(array, string.c_str(), sizeof(array));
```

And now I have an array that should look like this:

```
[a][0][d][g][i][w][0][0]...
```

So my question is, what is the most efficient way to convert all of the values inside the character array to ASCII key values? Most efficient as in least amount of time possible. If you do not understand what I mean by "ASCII key values", the final array should look like this:

```
[97][48][100][103][105][119][48][48]...
```

*Side Note: An ASCII key values table can be found [here](http://www.asciitable.com/).*

*Side Note: I already know how to convert the array values to ASCII, I am just looking for a much faster method.*

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say "ASCII key values', what data type are you meaning. Because 'a' IS [97] and '0' IS [48].  For example

`if( 'a' == 97 ){ printf("'a' is 97"); }`

Comment: The quickest way is to read the file into character arrays (or `std::vector<char>`s) directly, skipping the `std::string`s creation and conversion entirely...

Comment: @kuroineko I started out with vectors then decided to stick with an array and string. I am not trying to speed up the process of putting the file into a character array, just trying to convert between characters and ASCII faster.

Comment: @Synthetic Unless you need something else that you haven't included in the question, you don't seem to be understanding that the 'characters' and the 'ASCII' are already exactly the same.

Comment: @MatthewCarlson I know that they are the same, just in my case I want the characters to be stored in ASCII format.

Comment: @Synthetic thats what I'm telling you: The characters are already stored in ASCII.  Thats simply how your computer stores character arrays.  You can run this to confirm:
`printf("The character %c is the same as the number %d", 'a', 'a');

printf("The number %d is the same as the character %c", 97, 97);`

Comment: OK, so you know your characters are already encoded internaly in ASCII format, be them in a string, an array of chars or a vector. Maybe it's just me, but I don't see what more needs to be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a bunch of things about your locale, it's already stored as ASCII characters "under the hood", as in 'a'==97 in binary as a char (or whatever your compiler/system uses).  To get your system to treat 'a' as an integer value instead of a character, you just need to do `(int)'a'`, and any part of the string as `(int)array[index]`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    string sample = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for(char c : sample) {
        // NOTE: cast to (int) doesn't change value of 'c'.
        cout << c << '=' << (int)c << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a=97
b=98
c=99
d=100
e=101
f=102
g=103
h=104
i=105
j=106
k=107
l=108
m=109
n=110
o=111
p=112
q=113
r=114
s=115
t=116
u=117
v=118
w=119
x=120
y=121
z=122
```

Comment: Ok so I understand what you are doing in this case but am having problems implementing it. Do you mind showing me an example? Thanks.

Comment: @Synthetic MtRoad is pointing out that you appear to have already completed everything you have asked for.  Can you update the original question with what isn't working?

Comment: @MatthewCarlson The problem isn't that it is not working, just in my case I need the characters in the array to be stored as actual integers, so if I were to print the value of any element it would print the corresponding ASCII code.

Comment: @Synthetic this is what both MtRoad and I are both trying to tell you.  The characters in the array ARE stored as actual integers ( char is an integer value of 8 bytes on most computers, though technically it can be more. )  The default behavour of `cout << char` is to print it as the character value, but printf("%d", char) will show it as the number, as would `cout << 0+char`.

Comment: @Synthetic, you're confusing logical and physical representations.  Logically you think, 'a' is a character, 97 is an int!  However, physically, bitwise they're the same thing for when dealing with English and a few other cases, because the ASCII (integer) character codes are how you represent characters...

Comment: MathewCarlson and @MtRoad I just did not understand that you could tell the compiler to display a character in it's ASCII value and that you don't have convert. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, if you're looking for efficiency, then the initial `strncpy()` to an array accomplishes absolutely nothing. I don't see what it gets you. `string.c_str()` gives you exactly the same `const char *` that the array gets you. Keep everything in place, and avoid the overhead of needless copy.

Then, if you're looking for the most efficient way to convert a `char` value to decimal, it's going to be hard to beat doing it by hand.

```
unsigned char c=  /* wherever you get the next char from */

int zero=0;

if (c >= 100)
{
    zero=1;
    *ptr++ = (c/100) + '0';

    c = c % 100;
}

if (c >= 10 || zero)
{
    *ptr++ = (c / 10) + '0';
}

*ptr++ = (c % 10) + '0';
```

This should handily beat what `std::ostream` does, since it doesn't have to worry about all the baggage that `std::ostream`'s output formatting has to do.

Now, if the original `string` is `n=size()` bytes long, the longest possible size of the whole thing converted to decimal representation is three character per value, or `n*3`. Then, to account for the brackets, it's two more, for a grand total of `n*5`.

So:

```
 std::vector<char> output_buffer;

 output_buffer.resize(string.size()*5);

 auto ptr=&output_buffer[0];

 for (unsigned char c:string)
 {
       // the code segment above, with a few extra bits to append
       // the [ and the ], in the right place.
 }
```

When done, `ptr-&output_buffer[0]` gives you the actual number of characters written. You can trim the buffer, or copy it into a `std::string` of your own, your choice.

Comment: Astute discussion of the inefficiencies of dealing with std::ostream.

Comment: Well, std::ostream isn't really that inefficient, but if one is looking to squeeze out every available CPU cycle, and the formatting needs are simple, rolling your own is the way to go...

Comment: Sam, I totally agree.  This would be a limited case in which "roll your own" might actually be faster than the standard library.  In most general cases, you're wasting your time.